# Make all my word documents anonymous

Tags: microsoft-word, privacy

I'm submitting word documents for a school assignment.

I know that Word cleverly hides my name in the documents - somewhere. I'm not 100% sure what is

1. the best method from removing all this stuff from any given document
2. how to turn this "name saving" off so future documents don't save my name

Example - when i click on "File" as shown in the image below, at the top-left

[image]

The next screen that pops up has my name on it!

[image]

It is right under the giant blue smear.

Can I stop that name from showing up? Can I change it to anything else?

cheers!

Comment: Inspect Document allows you to remove that information.  I would just delete the author information.  You can do that by right clicking the author and selecting "remove person"

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). How will your assignments be marked if they are anonymous? What is the point of submitting an anonymous assignment? Nobody will know if you submitted it or not ...

Comment: @DavidPostill oh no, assignments are submitted via a unique id, that the examiners don't know.

Comment: @bharal Ah. OK. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I remove personal information from a word document?

Use the Document Inspector to find and remove personal information.

The "Document Properties and Personal Information" inspector includes "User name".

See instructions below (the source link includes include more information about the different "Inspectors" and the information they can remove).

---

#### Find and remove hidden data and personal information

> 1. Open the Word document that you want to inspect for hidden data and personal information.
> 2. Click the File tab, click Save As, and then type a name in the File name box to save a copy of your original document.
>
>    Important: It is a good idea to use the Document Inspector on a copy
>      of your original document, because it is not always possible to
>      restore the data that the Document Inspector removes.
> 3. In the copy of your original document, click the File tab, and then click Info.
> 4. Click Check for Issues, and then click Inspect Document.
> 5. In the Document Inspector dialog box, select the check boxes to choose the types of hidden content that you want to be inspected.
> 6. Click Inspect.
> 7. Review the results of the inspection in the Document Inspector dialog box.
> 8. Click Remove All next to the inspection results for the types of hidden content that you want to remove from your document.
>
>    Important:
>
>    If you remove hidden content from your document, you might not be
>      able to restore it by clicking Undo.
>
>    If you want to remove hidden data and personal information from
>      documents you save in the OpenDocument Text (.odt) format, you must
>      run the Document Inspector every time that you save the document in
>      this format.

Source [Remove hidden data and personal information by inspecting documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f)